# Firebase Realtime Database Internal Data Representation for Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**The Story**

I have an Android application which heavily relies on the Firebase Realtime Database. So far I do not have any problem using it.

But I need to store some highly sensitive data of the users in the database and I would not like to do that in plain text.

So, I have encrypted the data before storing them into the database. I can see the encrypted string in the Firebase Console.

**The Problem**

I need to check and verify how the data is internally represented by Firebase Database in my local device as I am storing the key for encryption in the database as well.

I have `setPersistenceEnabled()` for my database and thus Firebase stores these data locally in the users device. It is nowhere mentioned how Firebase does this internally. Does it store it as a JSON file or a SQLite database (most probable).

**My Attempt**

To dig deeper into the problem, I tried to pull the databases from my app.

I used,

```
"adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name ls /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/"
```

in my terminal to get a list of all database names for my app, and this is what I got,

```
app-debug-xxxx.firebaseio.com_default
app-debug-xxxx.firebaseio.com_default-journal
crash_reports
crash_reports-journal
```

So, these are my databases right? Are they regular SQLite databases? I was unable to read data from these files using the assumption that they are SQLite databases.

I personally think it is very important for us to know how the data is internally represented in Android so that we can make better decisions to store our data.

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: *firebaser here* The disk cache on Android is indeed stored in a sqlite database. While you can probably reverse engineer the data structure in that database, it is intentionally undocumented and may change over time without notice. The only documented way to access the data is through the Firebase SDK for Android.

Comment: I understand the point. But is it possible to read the data by reverse engineering the database files? Actually I am encrypting the data before storing them, but the KEY is also stored in the database itself. How can I ensure a better security in this respect? Any help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: Storing the secret key in the database is not safe. A better way is to encrypt your key using a keypair generated by the system keystore. See an [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Vault/src/com/example/android/vault/SecretKeyWrapper.java)

Comment: What is the minimum API to use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspecting the file you mentioned, yes it's indeed a SQLite database file (`app.firebaseio.com_default`).

The data is saved in `serverCache` table and it contains 2 columns: `path` (TEXT) and `value` (BLOB). `path` is the path to the data in firebase database, something like `/users/-KOasdbcde` and the `value` is the JSON value of that path.

**EDIT**

Here's the structure of that table
[image: firebase persistence]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on this? How the data is structured for different nested nodes? It would be even better if you can explain, how you were able to read the data from these files?

Comment: @AritraRoy I have updated my answer with the screenshot of what's inside that table. I use [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin) app for this, but you can also use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ if you're using desktop

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gave me a lot of insight into the internal data structure of Firebase. Actually I am already encrypting the data, but need to keep the KEY for the encryption in this database as well. But this can let anyone find the key and then decrypt the data. Can you suggest some better way for this?

Comment: hi @AritraRoy, looks like you need to host your own backend to save the key. I have no better idea than that since you enabled the disk persistence and the user who enabled the root access in their phone can read that database.

Comment: But that would still make the app only access its data when its online. I would not be able to call my backend and get the key when offline.

Comment: yes, that's the trade-off between security and availability. And if you save the key to the local disk for offline, someone can still find that key wherever it's stored. I'm sorry I don't have good security knowledge. :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for helping me in understanding the internal structure of Firebase Realtime database.