# Firebase SQL database

Tags: android, sql, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to add information the SQLite Database from Firebase that is created when the phone is offline. I have accessed it succesfully but when the cellphone is online again the row that I added is completly ignored. The interesting thing is that the only thing different is the POJO that I added in JSON format to the database,,but the difference is only the order, the rest its the same information.

The database has this columns:
`id (INTEGER)`
`path (TEXT)`
`type (TEXT)`
`part (INTEGER)`
`node (BLOB)`

The path is the path that the object is going to be saved to the Firebase Database, the type is "o" which I think that that indicates that the user has tried to sent information to the Firebase Database while beeing offline, the part seems to be always null and the node is the JSON format of the POJO that I have created. 
I have compared saved information that I added and the information that Firebase added by itself and like I said before the only difference is the order of the JSON format of the POJO... But I don't think that's why the row is beeing ignored. Please help

Comment: Are you asking about the Firebase disk cache described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38912167/4815718?

Comment: yes, I have added information to that database but it gets completly ignored when the user comes back online